# create and remove wireless network profiles

Tags: c#, .net, windows, networking

I want to make a tool that handles difference thing to the wifi configuration. It must be able to delete network profiles based on their name and create a new one. So far I have found this http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/ which seems to allow me to create a new profile, and then check for it afterwards, but it doesn't seem to allow me to delete existent profiles?

Comment: Looking at the source code there is a `deleteProfile(string ProfileName)` Method have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks :-) The mixture of me being tired and a very lite example wasn't good. I will take a closer look at that API class.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Hall answered it in a comment.

```
deleteProfile(string ProfileName)
```